# How to download and parse an sql file in java

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, database

I'm learning java/android development and I have an idea of an app that I want to make.
I want to make an app that displays a list of upcoming games (just an example) that I keep updating frequently. And in order to do that, it downloads a database file (or read it directly without downloading) and parse it to display the information each time the user opens the app.

I searched a lot and I didn't find any way to do it. I'll be thankful if someone tells me how.
I know that it's possible to use a RSS feed but I want to use database if possible.

Comment: Your English is _by far_ not terrible but I'm afraid your question is off-topic because you are asking for some kind of tutorial. Please refer to [ask]. SO is about specific programming problems, i.e. you should have a particular piece of code that doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend SQL database [H2](http://www.h2database.com). Simply include the .jar with your project (follow the website installation instructions) and use it in your code with:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:"+path_to_database);
con.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE games(name VARCHAR(80))");
con.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO games(name) VALUES('Halo 3')");
// etc...
```

Their documentation is pretty comprehensive to get you started with reading and writing from the database.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I'm try it.